# Tons of blank MySql Rows/Pages

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Somehow somone exploited my site and has inserted inserted the 48 pages(about 1440 rows) of nothing?

These images might help explain my issue

[image: Image 1]

[image]

As you can see in the first picture under rows, there is 2,530. There should only be about 1090 because 1440 of them are completely blank as shown on image 2

I have tried

```
DELETE FROM links WHERE url = '';
DELETE FROM links WHERE url IS NULL;
```

But none of these worked.
Does anyone know how to remove these?

Thanks Joel

Comment: What error message do you get back (if any)?

Comment: @peter-b I get ` 0 rows deleted. (Query took 0.0000 sec)`

Comment: run select count(*) FROM links please.

Comment: Cool, can you post some of the rows that you are trying to delete? Can't see any in the images.

Comment: Something you need to keep in mind about InnoDB, which you are using.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252008/why-does-my-innodb-table-have-a-weird-value-for-record-count  I doubt very seriously you have 2,530 rows at all. Run a select count (*) on that table and it'll probably clear this right up

Comment: @evanv it returns 1095...huh? and yes it still does say ~2,530 rows like in the picture

Comment: It's because PHPMyAdmin is using Show Table Status. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252008/why-does-my-innodb-table-have-a-weird-value-for-record-count. It'll explain what's going on. There is no problem here. And certainly nothing at all that should make you jump to a "someone exploited my site" conclusion.

Comment: @evanv Is there a way to clean that up to make it show the real number?
P.S yea someone did exploit my site which is why i said that, and i assumed this was related to it :P

Comment: Short answer, no. Also reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926259/why-is-the-estimated-rows-count-very-different-in-phpmyadmin-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference so this can be closed...

You are using the InnoDB storage engine (good choise btw). It does not maintain an exact row count of each table. And phpMyAdmin specifically uses SHOW TABLE STATUS, which for InnoDB is based on the estimates that InnoDB maintains of each table's row count. These esimates are inexact and can significantly off.  If you want to learn more about this issue, check out a great SO discussion on the topic here: [Why does my InnoDB table have a weird value for record count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252008/why-does-my-innodb-table-have-a-weird-value-for-record-count)

Bottom line, you don't have a problem at all. This is totally fine.